# Navigate to view model from left pane of mvxSlidingpanels

Tags: ios, mvvmcross, slidingmenu

I am trying to use this beautiful sliding panel by the Awesome Big Frank (https://github.com/fcaico/MvxSlidingPanels.Touch).

So i have implemented a left panel. When I click on an element, I want it to close the panel, and open a new view in the center pane.

Here is my code

```
public partial class LeftPanelView : MvxDialogViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.Root = new RootElement("Menu")
            {
                new Section("TEST")
                    {
                        new StyledStringElement("Produits enregistrés", ((LeftPanelViewModel)this.ViewModel).GoToSecondViewModel),
                    }
            };
    }
}
```

And in the LeftPaneViewModel I have this:

```
public class LeftPanelViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public LeftPanelViewModel ()
    {
    }

    public void GoToSecondViewModel()
    {
        this.ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>();
    }
}
```

As expected, it doesn't work.

```
2014-03-12 20:59:33.608 MvxSlidingPanelsSampleTouch[386:80b] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:  10.14 Navigate requested
2014-03-12 20:59:33.783 MvxSlidingPanelsSampleTouch[386:80b] mvx: Diagnostic:  10.31 Showing ViewModel SecondViewModel
2014-03-12 20:59:33.783 MvxSlidingPanelsSampleTouch[386:80b] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:  10.32 Navigate requested
2014-03-12 20:59:33.785 MvxSlidingPanelsSampleTouch[386:80b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2014-03-12 20:59:34.134 MvxSlidingPanelsSampleTouch[386:80b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SecondView: 0xe3f8590>.
2014-03-12 20:59:34.248 MvxSlidingPanelsSampleTouch[386:80b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

I understand that doing this cannot magically behave like I'd want.
But what I would like to understand, is how to modify the MvxSlidingPanelsTouchViewPresenter to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer... but from the trace it looks like `ShowViewModel` is being called twice on MvxTouchViewDispatcher

Somehow you are getting two trace lines like `TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:  10.32 Navigate requested` which is generated from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1ec7bc5f0307595c7ae11f56727dd0e9d2a2262f/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxTouchViewDispatcher.cs#L31

If you can work out why this navigation is occurring twice - and if you then can find a way to prevent it - then you should be able to avoid the "nested push animation" which is corrupting your UI.